# Thymeleaf dynamic bootstrap modal from edit button with html table

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a table

```
<table id="deleteTable" class="display table stripe">
    <thead>
    <tr class="tr-class" style="color: white!important; background-color: #41424a!important">
        <th>Friendly Name</th>
        <th>File Path</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="list: ${canDelete}">
            <td th:text="${list.friendlyName}" style="padding-left: 1em"></td>
            <td th:text="${list.filePath}"></td>
            <td style="padding-left: 2em; width: 10em">
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-warning" th:attr="data-target='#modal-warning'+${list.filePath}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 1em"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a style="padding-left: 3.2em; cursor: pointer;" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" data-toggle="modal">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This tables uses thymeleaf `th:each` to iterate through a list of objects. I want to be able to click on my trashcan icon within each row of the table and delete the row. I'm trying to pass a property of the object into the modal just as a test.

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" th:id="'modal-warning'+${list.filePath}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Remove Delete Permission</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="#" th:action="@{/users/deletePermissions/approve}" th:object="${canDelete}">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <span th:text="${list.filePath}"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-top: 1em; float: right;">
                        <button id="submitBtn" type="submit" class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised">
                            <span class="mdc-button__label">add delete permission</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I believe the issues is within the table:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-warning" th:attr="data-target='#modal-warning'+${list.filePath}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
```

or the modal:

```
th:id="'modal-warning'+${list.filePath}"
```

Update 1:

Forgot to include the error i'm receiving..

It's telling me that within my HTML page it cannot parse null for ${list.filePath} on line 84. Which is the line of code for the modal id.. it's like it's trying to parse that right now rather than on modal load

Comment: Provide details about the error you get

Comment: @Lasithds Stupid of me to forget.. thank you for reminding. Adding it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `${list}` is defined in your `th:each` -- and is only available to children tags of your `<tr />`.  By the time the modal html is parsed, the variable `${list}` is no longer in scope.  It is now null, which is why you are getting the error message.

You're going to have to change the way you are opening the modal (probably with javascript... unless you want to create a modal for each row of your table).

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect since. I think i'll have to look into the javascript way. I feel bad not confirming a delete for my users.

Answer (score 0):

Yout variable is null, you can add the modal inside the 3rd td of your table. to avoid the use of javascript